# How can I make a search filter in MVC5 that can filter on an enum

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, filter, enums

What's the correct code to make my search box filter my output of my (database,index,data.model?) (don't know how it's called)

I have 4 category's (soort , Transactietype , Beschrijving , Locatie)
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmGz2.jpg)

I was trying the tutorial of [mikesdotnetting on how to add "filtering"](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/243/MVC-5-with-EF-6-in-Visual-Basic-Sorting-Filtering-and-Paging)

but that's not really working out because he is adding a search only towards lastname and firstname  which are strings and I have enums too, where I also want to filter

```vb
Namespace Models
    Public Enum Soort
        Villa
        Kasteel
        GolfVilla
        LuxeAppartement
        Residentie
    End Enum
End NameSpace
```

and

```vb
Namespace Models
    Public Enum TransactieType
        Niets
        TeHuur
        TeKoop
        Beiden
    End Enum
End NameSpace
```

so my search box need to be able to filter
soort(enum),TransactieType(enum),beschrijving(string),locatie(string)

and show of my result

look of my pands/index

```vb
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of Exclimmo.Models.Pand)
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "Index"
End Code

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
@Using Html.BeginForm()
@<p>
    Find by Soort or TransactieType: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>
End Using
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("Soort", "Index", New With {.sortOrder =  ViewBag.soortSortParm})
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.ActionLink("TransactieType", "Index", New With {.sortOrder = ViewBag.TransactieTypeSortParm})
    </th>
    <th>
       Beschrijving
    </th>
    <th>
        Locatie
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@For Each item In Model
    @<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Soort)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.TransactieType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Beschrijving)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Locatie)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.Id}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", New With {.id = item.Id}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", New With {.id = item.Id})
        </td>
    </tr>
Next

</table>
```

and the look of my pandcontroller(function index)

```vb
Function Index(ByVal sortOrder As String) As ActionResult
    ViewBag.soortSortParm = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder), "soort_desc", String.Empty)
    ViewBag.TransactieTypeSortParm = If(sortOrder = "TransactieType", "TransactieType_desc", "TransactieType")

    Dim pand = From s In db.Panden Select s

    Select Case sortOrder
        Case "soort_desc"
            pand = pand.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.Soort)
        Case "TransactieType"
            pand = pand.OrderBy(Function(s) s.TransactieType)
        Case "TransactieType_desc"
            pand = pand.OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.TransactieType)
        Case Else
            pand = pand.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Soort)
    End Select
    Return View(pand.ToList())
End Function
```

I am new in MVC so if you need other code please tell me what I need to add more.

So what I was trying is this :

```vb
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) Then
    pand = pand.Where(Function(s) s.Soort.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
                                  Or s.TransactieType.ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))
End If
```

but this can't work because the use of `s.Soort.ToUpper` as I ready the `.ToUpper` is to let string convert to all uppercase but this can't work towards my `s.Soort` because this is an `enum`

so whats the correct code to met it search in : soort(enum),TransactieType(enum),beschrijving(string),locatie(string)

So after the answer of `s.Soort.ToString().ToUpper()` and `s.TransactieType.ToString().ToUpper()`

```vb
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString) Then
    pand = pand.Where(Function(s) s.Soort.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()) _
                                          Or s.TransactieType.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(searchString.ToUpper()))
End If
```

I have the ability to startup the site in a browser but if I use the filter I get the next error

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

this point towards

```vb
Return View(pand.ToList())
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What exact problem are you having?

Comment: hello i added how far i got maybe that shows what i am telling here @John Saunders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `s.Soort.ToString().ToUpper()`.

This will first convert your `enum` to a string, and *then* upper case the string.

Comment: this worked , my error's are gone but now it got an error if i run the project and do a search @John Saunders

Comment: That would seem to be a separate problem, so ask a separate question. Also, since this answer solved your problem, you should mark it as the accepted answer so that other users who find this question know which answer solved the problem.

Comment: thanks for looking into it hope to see you @ my next question @John Saunders